# Ubuntu Phpmyadmin - No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted,

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

In ubuntu showing this below error when I try to import sql file in phpmyadmin.

No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration

Comment: please edit your post and add code fences to add your error log to increase readability.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: How large is the SQL file you're trying to import?

Answer (score 0):

1. First find tmp path from this file

/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

**php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp**

2. When I checked permission it was not writeable
   /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp

So update the permission of this folder to 775

sudo chmod -R 775 tmp

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER tmp